# Restrict HTTP methods (only GET and POST) in Spring Web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

For security purpose regarding my Springboot application, one client is asking for a restriction of the allowed methods

Indeed, although my application only provides `GET` and `POST` methods, when I run `nikto -ssl -h localhost:8181` I get the following messages:

```
+ Allowed HTTP Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS 
+ OSVDB-397: HTTP method ('Allow' Header): 'PUT' method could allow clients to save files on the web server.
+ OSVDB-5646: HTTP method ('Allow' Header): 'DELETE' may allow clients to remove files on the web server.
```

In these circumstances, I am looking for a way to restrict the HTTP methods allowed by my Springboot application and effectively expose only `GET` and `POST` methods

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? If not you could write a filter to limit the methods available else you could let Spring Security handle the allowance.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in Spring you develop a custom `HandlerInterceptor` and from the `preHandle` method, you can block the incoming request by returning false from the method. The framework will then stop doing any additional API calls further down the chain.

```java
public class BlockingHttpMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {    
        if (HttpMethod.GET.matches(request.getMethod()) 
         || HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.getMethod())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value());
            return false;
        }
}
```

And lastly you can register this handler, potentially providing a strategy on when the handler should be executed.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BlockingHttpMethodInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/**"); // paths that should use the interceptor
    }
}
```

Comment: same thing than with previous answer: this method is working: non-`GET` and non-`POST` methods are correctly filtered. 

However, when launching `nikto -ssl -h localhost:8181` I still get the same messages saying that `GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` are allowed!

I think that, additionally, I have to change the value of a header attribute (certainly `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) but I don't know how: any idea?

Comment: @Nico -  Filters intercept requests before they reach the DispatcherServlet, making them ideal for coarse-grained tasks such as Authentication whereas HandlerIntercepors intercept requests between the DispatcherServlet and our Controllers, so it's not a good choice to block an HTTP request using an interceptor, instead of its good for handling cross-cutting concern like logging. [check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter#key-differences-and-use-cases)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your implementation of `OncePerRequestFilter` which  aims to guarantee a single execution per request dispatch, example as follows:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class MethodFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter { 

    @Override 
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) 
                    throws ServletException, IOException { 
        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET") || request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
        } else { 
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        } 
    }
}
```

This will also disable the `OPTIONS` method which returns all possible API options.

Comment: this method is working: non-`GET` and non-`POST` methods are correctly filtered. 

However, when launching `nikto -ssl -h localhost:8181` I still get the same messages saying that `GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` are allowed!

I think that, additionally, I have to change the value of a header attribute (certainly `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) but I don't know how: any idea?

Comment: @PhilippeMESMEUR - You can also try adding CrossOrigin on the Controller or even at the global level [check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors#2-crossorigin-on-the-controller)