# Allow only GET and POST HTTP methods for "*" target in Spring Web application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

> *this question is the continuation of [Restrict HTTP methods (only GET and POST) in Spring Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529337/restrict-http-methods-only-get-and-post-in-spring-web-application): the original question was not correct because of a bad understanding of the client request*

A client ran a pen test on my SpringBoot application. Although my application only provides `GET` and `POST` methods, the pen test reported:

```
Options allowed : GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

**The client wants to effectively only allow `GET` and `POST` methods**

I found two ways to get the same output as the client

- using `nikto`

  ```
    nikto -ssl -h https://localhost:8181
    ...
    + Allowed HTTP Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS 
    + OSVDB-397: HTTP method ('Allow' Header): 'PUT' method could allow clients to save files on the web server.
    + OSVDB-5646: HTTP method ('Allow' Header): 'DELETE' may allow clients to remove files on the web server.
  ```
- using `curl`

  ```
    curl -k -i --request-target "*" -X OPTIONS https://localhost:8181
    ...
    HTTP/1.1 200 
    Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
  ```

It seems that both are asking for `OPTIONS` method at`*` target

In this circumstance, I am looking for a way to configure/tune my SpringBoot application in order to answer `Allow: GET, POST`

I tried the solutions given in [Restrict HTTP methods (only GET and POST) in Spring Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529337/restrict-http-methods-only-get-and-post-in-spring-web-application) but unfortunately, they are *"only"* blocking requests made on non `GET` and `POST` methods

**I may be wrong but I think that the solution would be, *at least for `*` target*, to provide a HTTP header having `Allow` tag with only values `GET` and `POST`**

Thank you for help

Comment: I have two possible ways in mind; first one is to use antMatchers in springsecurity configuration and the other one ise to use configuration on http server level (using AllowMethods configuration on Apache). I did not test this, just a quick suggestion.

Comment: thank you for the answer but unfortunately I don't know how to do so using `antMatchers`: any help is welcome